# Executing hibernate template's findByNamedQuery

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I'm pretty new to hibernate and I was trying it out in one of my applications. I chose to use annotation session factory bean and my editor generated entity classes for each table from the DB which had named queries. `hibernateTemplate.findByAll` worked fine. But when I tried `hibernateTemplate.findByNamedQuery("findById", "<some_id>")`, it gave an error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based.` After a bit of googling, tried out multiple solutions:

1. Changed the namedQuery that was generated by editor from : `@NamedQuery(name = "Table.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM Table t WHERE t.id = :id")`, to : `@NamedQuery(name = "Table.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM Table t WHERE t.id = ?")` but got the same error.
2. Tried using `hibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam` but ended up getting error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!`

I can use hibernateTemplate.find() to achieve this but how do I use findByNamedQuery/Param methods to achieve the same since the documentation says these methods may be used to fetch records based on a field?